# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo...NullPointerException

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to populate a single listview with a textview but i am getting the following error on line 60 that is

```
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here is my complete log.

```
04-16 10:51:38.953: E/AndroidRuntime(3068): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-16 10:51:38.953: E/AndroidRuntime(3068): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-16 10:51:38.953: E/AndroidRuntime(3068):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
04-16 10:51:38.953: E/AndroidRuntime(3068):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-16 10:51:38.953: E/AndroidRuntime(3068):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
04-16 10:51:38.953: E/AndroidRuntime(3068):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-16 10:51:38.953: E/AndroidRuntime(3068):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-16 10:51:38.953: E/AndroidRuntime(3068):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
04-16 10:51:38.953: E/AndroidRuntime(3068):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-16 10:51:38.953: E/AndroidRuntime(3068):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-16 10:51:38.953: E/AndroidRuntime(3068):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
04-16 10:51:38.953: E/AndroidRuntime(3068):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
04-16 10:51:38.953: E/AndroidRuntime(3068):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-16 10:51:38.953: E/AndroidRuntime(3068): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-16 10:51:38.953: E/AndroidRuntime(3068):     at s..onCreate(Urgence.java:60)
04-16 10:51:38.953: E/AndroidRuntime(3068):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-16 10:51:38.953: E/AndroidRuntime(3068):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
04-16 10:51:38.953: E/AndroidRuntime(3068):     ... 11 more
```

This is my List class

```
public class ListClass extends Activity 
{



    // Array of strings storing country names
    String[] countries = new String[] {
            "Services opposition", "Service Carte bancaire a l'etranger"
    };

    // Array of integers points to images stored in /res/drawable-ldpi/
    int[] flags = new int[]{
            R.drawable.arrow,
            R.drawable.arrow
    };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.urgence);

        // Each row in the list stores country name, currency and flag
        List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();        

        for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
            hm.put("txt", countries[i]);
            hm.put("flag", Integer.toString(flags[i]) );            
            aList.add(hm);        
        }

        // Keys used in Hashmap
        String[] from = { "txt","flag"};

        // Ids of views in listview_layout
        int[] to = { R.id.single_text,R.id.single_image};        

        // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
        // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.listview_layout, from, to);

        // Getting a reference to listview of main.xml layout file
        ListView listView = ( ListView ) findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Setting the adapter to the listView
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);                                
    }



}
```

Anyone know why my adapter is null

**Update :** 
This is my listview from my xml file

```
<ListView 
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: R.layout.urgence post this file too

Comment: Can you post your `SimpleAdapter` code?

Comment: Why you convering Integer.toString(flags[i]).. ?

Comment: there is no simple adapter code dude

Comment: @yakusha Try my answer.. it should work

Comment: @RajeshCP why do you deleted you answer.. instead you can edit it..any how I have commented that to let you know before somebody downvote

Comment: Its Okay, any way its about 15 Points never mind :)\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is seen when the id in the activity xml is different to that referred to in the java class.

Change the below line

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

to

```
android:id="@+id/list"
```

in your XML file.

Answer (score 3):

It's not your adapter that's `null`; it's `listView`. (A null `adapter` would not generate an exception immediately at that line.) Your  layout—`layout/urgence.xml`— does not define a view with id `list`. Fix your layout and that line should then work.

**EDIT** Based on your update, the problem is that you are trying to find a view with id `R.id.list` and you should be trying to find a view with id `android.R.id.list`. `R` and `android.R` are two different things.

Alternatively, you can change your layout to use your own `id/list`:

```
<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```